# how to use terragrunt as pre-processor and generate terraform files

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Is it possible to use terragrunt to as a pre-processor to be later used by terraform, can someone share thoughts around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone else; solved it by invoking `terragrunt` with a spoofed `terraform`

```
$cat tfspoof
#! /bin/bash
#
# Filename    : tfspoof
# Date        : 21 May 2021
# Author      : Balaji Venkataraman (xbalaji)
# Description : terragrunt demo - terraform spoof executable
# Usage       :
#

[[ "$1" == "--version" ]] && version=$(terraform --version) && echo "$version" && exit 0
echo "other commands passed: " $*
```

Invoke `terragrunt` with the option for tf

```
terragrunt plan --terragrunt-tfpath ./tfspoof
```

`terragrunt` now generates the files without actual invocation of `terraform`.